# Check if last list item is equal to length Xamarin Forms binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, datatrigger

I am trying to hide last Grid column. I'm trying to do it with DataTrigger, this is how my trigger looks like:

```
            <ResourceDictionary>
               <Style x:Key="HideLastVerticalLine" TargetType="BoxView">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Items, Path=Items.LastOrDefault}"
                        TargetType="BoxView"
                        Value="{Binding Items.Length}">
                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </ResourceDictionary>

           <BoxView Style="{StaticResource HideLastVerticalLine}" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black"/>
```

I'm applying this DataTrigger to a BoxView, which contains a vertical line separator (I want something as Trim(), just to remove last separator line.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you post an image and complete code of what you are trying to accomplish? You want to hide an entire column or just a boxview?

Comment: The Items.LastOrDefault is a method, so the binding will not work.

Comment: So I have a DataTemplate creating 2 columns for every item on a list. First column will be a listview, second column will be separator vertical line. I want to hide second column of last item (in order to not show the vertical separator line on the last item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector) to achieve this.

The sample is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/templates-datatemplateselector/).

Create two DataTemplates, one for `LastViewCell` and one for other `ViewCells`:

```
public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate NormalTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate LastCellTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
    {

        var lastItem = Items.LastOrDefault();

        return lastItem = item ? LastCellTemplate : NormalTemplate;
    }
}
```

Choose to use which `DataTemplate` by checking if the item is last Item.

Answer (score 1):

- Create Bindable Layout.
- Create separate template selector class.
- The class used to populate the bindable layout itemsource must have new property isLast bool.
- Update the list with last element as true.
- Now Bind this new list with the bindable layout you are using on the view.
- Don’t forget to add your templateselector on resource dictionary of that page.
  For updating last item in list to isLast = true use.

```
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in list) // here updating last element of list islast =true
    {
    item.IsLast = (index == list.Count - 1);
    index++;
    }
```